# Resolving context driven parameters with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to find a better way to resolve context-driven parameters using Autofac. Consider the following code :

```cs
        builder.RegisterType<SqlDatabaseResourceFactory>().WithParameter("connectionStringKey", "MyConnectionStringKey").As<DatabaseResourceFactory>();

        builder.RegisterType<ATypeRepository>().As<IATypeRepository>().PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterType<BTypeRepository>().As<IBTypeRepository>().PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterType<CTypeRepository>().As<ICTypeRepository>().PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterType<DTypeRepository>().As<IDTypeRepository>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

In this case, each "Repository" has a property ResourceFactory, typed DatabaseResourceFactory, that has a local default (for compatibility with legacy code). This works great as long as all the types needing ResourceFactory injected use the same connection string.

If, say, C and D repositories needed a different connection string, though, this solution would no longer work. The best work-around I can think of is to use something like the following

```cs
       builder.RegisterType<ATypeRepository>()
              .As<IATypeRepository>()
              .OnActivating(c => c.Instance.ResourceFactory = new SqlDatabaseResourceFactory("MyConnectionStringKey"));
```

But this now needs doing for each repository type registered, which seems overly repetitive and clunky. Is there a better solution to this type of problem. Is this problem an indication of some underlying architectural issue?

Answer (score 1):

> If, say, C and D repositories needed a different connection string,

If C and D need a different connection, they should get their own abstraction. For instance define a `IBillingDatabaseResourceFactory` and `IShippingDatabaseResourceFactory`. This resolves the ambiguity that's currently in your design and DI configuration.

Comment: While this would cleanly solve the dependency resolution issue, it seems that I would be creating a number of anemic interfaces solely for the purpose of differentiating the different contexts in which DatabaseResourceFactory was used (i.e., different connection strings). I'm not sure that it makes sense to couple the generic DatabaseResourceFactory (and its implementation specific children, i.e., SqlDatabaseResourceFactory) to interfaces specific to one application domain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 builder.Register(c => new CTypeRepository(new SqlDatabaseResourceFactory("C-connectionstring")).As<ICTypeRepository>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: This would work too, but it seems to have the same problem as the OnActivating solution I pointed out in the original question. Wouldn't I still have to individually register the connection string for each type needing a repository? I was hoping to find a solution where I could eliminate this redundancy and somehow specify the connection strings per group of items.

Comment: If you can have multiple connection strings per different instances, you cannot avoid specifying a mapping somehow.  Think of it that every time you instantiate, you have to specify which one.  Either by providing it directly, or via an interface, or possibly different instances of the factory, as suggested by others here.